# Send Verification Code to email for two step verification using Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swift5, one-time-password

I'm making an iOS app where user sign in using email and password. When they enter both (email, password), then I want firebase to send verification **code** (not **link**) to verify user before they enter to the app, for security purposes. It is something like phoneAuth but I want it to be an email instead. Does firebase has this ability?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this is not something that is built into Firebase Authentication's email+password provider.

The simplest way I can think of getting close to this, is using the Admin SDK to [generate an email verification link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#generateemailverificationlink), parse the oobCode/actionCode out of that, and then in the client [call `applyActionCode` to verify the email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler#create_the_email_action_handler_page) ([iOS API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#applyactioncode_:completion:)).